# How to add attribute value in tier price?

Tags: magento2, tierprice

I have create configure product and add one virtual product in configurable product.then add tier price in virtual product.

[image]

I have create one attribute and this attribute value get front-end product details page .when i select 1 value in drop-down then add 1 value in tier price.

[image]

**Actual result** :-Addition of dropdown value in tier price

[image]

Comment: Please give me any solution?This is urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to override

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

template file, add below code at bottom and replace custom attribute names:

> NOTE: Below code is for 2 values in your field. Please take count of values and do respective changes.

```
<?php
    $myattribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    $myattribute_color_qty = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color_custom')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    ?>

    <select id="colorprice_final">
    <option value="0">Please Select Quantity</option>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $myattribute_color_qty; $i++){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    </br>
    <script>

    jQuery("#colorprice_final").change(function(){

        var colorprice = jQuery(this).val();
        var pri =jQuery('.color-price').text();
        var add_arr = new Array();
        add_arr = '<?php echo $myattribute; ?>';
        add_arr = add_arr.split(',');
        var total = [];
        var tier_arr = new Array();
        jQuery('.tiercustprice').each(function(){
            var str = jQuery(this).text() ;
            tier_arr.push(str.replace('$',''));
        });
        if(colorprice == '1')
        {
        for( var i = 0; i < add_arr.length; i++)
            {
                total.push(parseFloat(add_arr[i])+parseFloat(tier_arr[i]));
            }
        }else if (colorprice == '2') {
            for( var i = 0; i < add_arr.length; i++)
            {
                total.push(parseFloat(tier_arr[i])+parseFloat(add_arr[i])*2);
            }
        }
        console.log(total);
    });
    </script>
```

In console you can see **Total** now.